# Solving Minimizing the Driving Distance in Ride Sharing Systems code in Python with PuLP library

Tags: python, typeerror, linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

> "The aim is to match riders to drivers, satisfying car capacities and individual trip constraints, while minimizing the total driven distance. Drivers and riders have some flexibility in negotiating specific pick-up and drop-off locations, thus trips are initially arranged based on a smaller set of standard locations, representing small towns, districts, or main junctions in the road network. Many users may thus share the same origin or destination. We assume travel times between all pairs of locations are known, and we assume all drivers will use the same route between a given pair. Similarly, we assume time windows are based on standard intervals e.g. 15 minutes, and users will specify their latest arrival time at that granularity. A driver’s trip offer is specified as a route from start to finish, a time window of earliest departure and latest arrival, and the number of available seats for passengers. A rider’s trip request specifies a start location destination and time window. We assume a driver will drive, regardless of whether or not a match is made; a rider who is not offered a match may drive on their own, outside the system, with a given probability, and otherwise, they will take public transport. Each driver that is allocated one or more riders must be given a departure time and an arrival time at each point on the route, such that the time gap between any pair of locations is not less than the known travel times. For a rider to be assigned to a driver, the rider’s start and finish locations must be on the driver's route in the right order, and the driver’s times must satisfy the rider’s time window. Multiple riders can be allocated to the same driver, as long as the number of passengers traveling between locations on the route does not exceed the available seats. A driver is served when at least one rider is assigned to the driver’s trip; a rider is served when he or she is assigned to a trip. A solution to the ride-sharing problem is an assignment of matching drivers to riders that satisfies the above constraints. An optimal solution minimizes the total driven distance - that is, the sum of the route distance for drivers, and for the fixed proportion of unserved riders"

I try to write this problem's code in Python with PuLP. The problem is offline and we have passenger's and driver's parameters before start time of work. I want to match these with each other with this code:

```py
from pulp import *
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
D = ['driver1', 'driver2'] 
R = ['rider1', 'rider2', 'rider3','rider4','rider5']
V = ['location1', 'location2', 'location3', 'location4', 'location5', 'location6', 'location7'] 
G = nx.DiGraph()
edges = {
    ('location1', 'location2'): 10, 
    ('location2', 'location3'): 12, 
    ('location3', 'location4'): 15,
    ('location4', 'location2'): 10,
    ('location6', 'location5'): 10,
    ('location1', 'location5'): 10,
    ('location4', 'location1'): 10,
    ('location5', 'location6'): 10,
    ('location1', 'location4'): 10, 
    ('location2', 'location5'): 10, 
    ('location1', 'location6'): 10,
    ('location4', 'location5'): 10,
    ('location5', 'location3'): 20,
    ('location1', 'location6'): 50,
    ('location5', 'location7'): 10,
    ('location5', 'location2'): 5,
    ('location7', 'location3'): 5
    }

G.add_weighted_edges_from((u, v, w) for (u, v), w in edges.items())

vsr = {'rider1': 'location1', 'rider2': 'location2', 'rider3': 'location3', 'rider4': 'location2', 'rider5': 'location5'} 

ver = {'rider1': 'location4', 'rider2': 'location5', 'rider3': 'location6', 'rider4': 'location5', 'rider5': 'location7'} 
num_people = {'rider1': 1, 'rider2': 2, 'rider3': 1 ,'rider4': 2,'rider5':1}

πd = {'driver1': ['location1', 'location2', 'location3', 'location4', 'location5', 'location6'],
      'driver2': ['location2', 'location3', 'location4', 'location1', 'location5', 'location7']}

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_color='lightblue', node_size=1500)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels)
shortest_paths = dict(nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path(G))
shortest_path_lengths = dict(nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(G))
stv_v_prime = {}
dv_v_prime = {}
for v, lengths in shortest_path_lengths.items():
    for v_prime, length in lengths.items():
        dv_v_prime[(v, v_prime)] = length

for v, lengths in shortest_path_lengths.items():
    for v_prime, length in lengths.items():
        stv_v_prime[(v, v_prime)] = (length * 5) / 60

dvsr_ver = {}
for rider in R:
    start_location = vsr[rider]
    end_location = ver[rider]
    shortest_distance = dv_v_prime[(start_location, end_location)]
    dvsr_ver[rider] = {'shortest_distance': shortest_distance}

for rider, location in vsr.items():
    plt.text(pos[location][0], pos[location][1]+0.1, f"{rider} start", horizontalalignment='center', color='green')
for rider, location in ver.items():
    plt.text(pos[location][0], pos[location][1]-0.1, f"{rider} end", horizontalalignment='center', color='red')
for driver, path in πd.items():
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=[(path[i], path[i+1]) for i in range(len(path)-1)], edge_color='yellow', width=2)
#plt.show()
etd={'driver1': 8, 'driver2': 8}
ltd={'driver1': 24, 'driver2': 24}
qd = {'driver1': 4, 'driver2': 4}
etr = {'rider1': 8, 'rider2': 8, 'rider3': 8, 'rider4':8,'rider5':9} 
ltr = {'rider1': 24, 'rider2': 24, 'rider3': 24, 'rider4':24,'rider5':24} 
M = 1000
startsπd_v = {d: {v: [] for v in V} for d in D}
endsπd_v = {d: {v: [] for v in V} for d in D}
for d in D:
    for r in R:
        if vsr[r] in πd[d]:
            startsπd_v[d][vsr[r]].append(r)
        if ver[r] in πd[d]:
            endsπd_v[d][ver[r]].append(r)
            
predπd_v = {}

for d in πd:
    predπd_v[d] = []
    for i in range(1, len(πd[d])):
        predπd_v[d].append(πd[d][i-1])
        
default_distance = 0         

prob = LpProblem("Ride_Sharing_Problem", LpMinimize)

#Decision Variables
yd_r = LpVariable.dicts("match", ((d, r) for d in D for r in R), 0, 1, LpBinary)
td_v = LpVariable.dicts("departure_time", ((d, v) for d in D for v in V), etd, ltd, LpContinuous)

#Auxiliary Variables
z_r = LpVariable.dicts("served_rider", (r for r in R), 0, 1, LpBinary)
od_v = LpVariable.dicts("car_occupancy", ((d, v) for d in D for v in V), 0, None, LpInteger)

#Our objective is to minimize:
prob += lpSum([yd_r[d, r] * dvsr_ver[r].get('shortest_distance', default_distance) for d in D ]) + lpSum((1 - z_r[r]) * dvsr_ver[r].get('shortest_distance', default_distance) for r in R)

for d in D:
    for r in R:
        if vsr[r] not in πd[d] or ver[r] not in πd[d]:
            prob += yd_r[d, r] == 0
for d in D:
    for r in R:
        prob += lpSum(yd_r[d, r] for r in R if etr[r] < etd[d] or ltr[r] > ltd[d]) == 0

for r in R:
    prob += lpSum(yd_r[d, r] for d in D) <= 1
for r in R:    
    prob += lpSum(yd_r[d, r] for d in D) == z_r[r]
for r in R:
    prob += z_r[r] >= yd_r['driver1', r] + yd_r['driver2', r] - 1
    prob += z_r[r] <= yd_r['driver1', r]
    prob += z_r[r] <= yd_r['driver2', r]
    prob += lpSum(yd_r[d, r] for d in D) >= z_r[r]
for d in D:
    for v in V:
        prob += od_v[d, v] <= qd[d]    
for d in D:
    prob += lpSum(yd_r[d, r] * num_people[r] for r in R) <= qd[d]    
for d in D:
    for v in V:
        if v in predπd_v:
            prob += od_v[d, v] == od_v[d, predπd_v[v]] + lpSum(yd_r[d, r] * num_people[r] for r in startsπd_v[v]) - lpSum(yd_r[d, r] * num_people[r] for r in endsπd_v[v])

        for r in R:
            if d == r:
                prob += yd_r[d, r] * etr[r] <= td_v[d, vsr[r]]
                prob += M - td_v[d, ver[r]] >= (M - ltr[r]) * yd_r[d, r]
time_window = 1                  
for d in D:
     for v in V:
        if v in predπd_v:
        
           prob += td_v[d, v] >= td_v[d, predπd_v[v]] + stv_v_prime[(predπd_v[v], v)]
            
for d in D:
    for r in R:
        for v in V:
            for v_prime in V:
                if v != v_prime:
                    match = int(vsr[r] == v and ver[r] == v_prime)
                    prob += match * yd_r[d, r] - time_window <= td_v[d, v] - td_v[d, v_prime]
                    prob += match * yd_r[d, r] + time_window >= td_v[d, v] - td_v[d, v_prime]
for d in D:
    for i in range(len(πd[d])-1):
        prob += td_v[d, πd[d][i+1]] >= td_v[d, πd[d][i]] + stv_v_prime[(πd[d][i], πd[d][i+1])]
prob.solve()
for v in prob.variables():
    #print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
    #print("Objective:", value(model.objective))
    print("Objective:", value(prob.objective))
```

but I couldn't determine the mistake for this error:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not dict
```

Comment: The first major problem is that in `prob += lpSum` your objective, you have not defined `r` and it's probably using some left-over garbage from a previous iteration (`for r in R`). This is the risk you run when you dump everything in the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comments, the first major problem is that in `prob += lpSum` your objective, you have not defined `r` and it's probably using some left-over garbage from a previous iteration (`for r in R`). This is the risk you run when you dump everything in the global namespace.

The next problem is that you tried to pass entire dictionaries `etd`, `ltd` into bound parameters. PuLP doesn't work that way - it requires scalars for bounds.

Don't intersperse graphing and business logic. I have commented out the graphing. If you want to reintroduce this, do it in a different function.

Finally, this code:

```py
for d in D:
    for r in R:
        prob += lpSum(yd_r[d, r] for r in R if etr[r] < etd[d] or ltr[r] > ltd[d]) == 0
```

makes no sense; it's iterating over `r` twice. Surely you meant for `lpSum` to contain a generator that iterates over `r` as it does now, without an outer `for` that also iterates over `r`.

The following fixes those issues, does a significant amount of namespace cleanup, and gets the problem to the point where it executes (and fails due to being infeasible).

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

import pulp
import networkx
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class NetworkVars(NamedTuple):
    drivers: tuple[str, ...]
    riders: tuple[str, ...]
    locations: tuple[str, ...]
    num_people: dict[str, int]
    vsr: dict[str, str]
    ver: dict[str, str]
    etr: dict[str, int]
    etd: dict[str, int]
    ltr: dict[str, int]
    ltd: dict[str, int]
    qd: dict[str, int]
    πd: dict[str, list[str]]
    predπd_v: dict[str, list[str]]
    startsπd_v: dict[str, dict[str, list[str]]]
    endsπd_v: dict[str, dict[str, list[str]]]
    stv_v_prime: dict[tuple[str, str], float]
    dvsr_ver: dict[str, dict[str, int]]

    @classmethod
    def default(cls) -> 'NetworkVars':
        drivers = ('driver1', 'driver2')
        riders = ('rider1', 'rider2', 'rider3', 'rider4', 'rider5')
        locations = ('location1', 'location2', 'location3', 'location4', 'location5', 'location6', 'location7')
        graph = networkx.DiGraph()
        edges = {
            ('location1', 'location2'): 10,
            ('location2', 'location3'): 12,
            ('location3', 'location4'): 15,
            ('location4', 'location2'): 10,
            ('location6', 'location5'): 10,
            ('location1', 'location5'): 10,
            ('location4', 'location1'): 10,
            ('location5', 'location6'): 10,
            ('location1', 'location4'): 10,
            ('location2', 'location5'): 10,
            ('location1', 'location6'): 10,
            ('location4', 'location5'): 10,
            ('location5', 'location3'): 20,
            ('location1', 'location6'): 50,
            ('location5', 'location7'): 10,
            ('location5', 'location2'): 5,
            ('location7', 'location3'): 5,
        }
        graph.add_weighted_edges_from((u, v, w) for (u, v), w in edges.items())

        vsr = {'rider1': 'location1', 'rider2': 'location2', 'rider3': 'location3', 'rider4': 'location2',
               'rider5': 'location5'}

        ver = {'rider1': 'location4', 'rider2': 'location5', 'rider3': 'location6', 'rider4': 'location5',
               'rider5': 'location7'}
        num_people = {'rider1': 1, 'rider2': 2, 'rider3': 1, 'rider4': 2, 'rider5': 1}

        πd = {'driver1': ['location1', 'location2', 'location3', 'location4', 'location5', 'location6'],
              'driver2': ['location2', 'location3', 'location4', 'location1', 'location5', 'location7']}

        # pos = networkx.spring_layout(G=graph)
        # networkx.draw(G=graph, pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_color='lightblue', node_size=1500)
        # labels = networkx.get_edge_attributes(G=graph, name='weight')
        # networkx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G=graph, pos=pos, edge_labels=labels)
        # shortest_paths = dict(networkx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path(G=graph))
        shortest_path_lengths: dict[str, dict[str, int]] = dict(
            networkx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(G=graph)
        )
        stv_v_prime = {}
        dv_v_prime = {}
        for v, lengths in shortest_path_lengths.items():
            for v_prime, length in lengths.items():
                dv_v_prime[(v, v_prime)] = length

        for v, lengths in shortest_path_lengths.items():
            for v_prime, length in lengths.items():
                stv_v_prime[(v, v_prime)] = length * 5 / 60

        dvsr_ver = {}
        for rider in riders:
            start_location = vsr[rider]
            end_location = ver[rider]
            shortest_distance = dv_v_prime[(start_location, end_location)]
            dvsr_ver[rider] = {'shortest_distance': shortest_distance}

        # for rider, location in vsr.items():
        #     plt.text(pos[location][0], pos[location][1] + 0.1, f"{rider} start", horizontalalignment='center', color='green')
        # for rider, location in ver.items():
        #     plt.text(pos[location][0], pos[location][1] - 0.1, f"{rider} end", horizontalalignment='center', color='red')
        # for driver, path in πd.items():
        #     networkx.draw_networkx_edges(
        #         G=graph, pos=pos,
        #         edgelist=[(path[i], path[i + 1]) for i in range(len(path) - 1)],
        #         edge_color='yellow',
        #         width=2,
        #     )
        # plt.show()
        etd = {'driver1': 8, 'driver2': 8}
        ltd = {'driver1': 24, 'driver2': 24}
        qd = {'driver1': 4, 'driver2': 4}
        etr = {'rider1': 8, 'rider2': 8, 'rider3': 8, 'rider4': 8, 'rider5': 9}
        ltr = {'rider1': 24, 'rider2': 24, 'rider3': 24, 'rider4': 24, 'rider5': 24}

        startsπd_v = {d: {v: [] for v in locations} for d in drivers}
        endsπd_v = {d: {v: [] for v in locations} for d in drivers}
        for d in drivers:
            for r in riders:
                if vsr[r] in πd[d]:
                    startsπd_v[d][vsr[r]].append(r)
                if ver[r] in πd[d]:
                    endsπd_v[d][ver[r]].append(r)

        predπd_v = {}

        for d in πd:
            predπd_v[d] = []
            for i in range(1, len(πd[d])):
                predπd_v[d].append(πd[d][i - 1])

        return cls(
            drivers=drivers, riders=riders, locations=locations, num_people=num_people,
            vsr=vsr, ver=ver, etr=etr, etd=etd, ltr=ltr, ltd=ltd,
            predπd_v=predπd_v, startsπd_v=startsπd_v, endsπd_v=endsπd_v,
            stv_v_prime=stv_v_prime, qd=qd, πd=πd, dvsr_ver=dvsr_ver,
        )


def make_lp_vars(network: NetworkVars) -> tuple[
    pulp.LpProblem,  # prob
    dict[tuple[str, str], pulp.LpVariable],  # yd_r
    dict[str, pulp.LpVariable],              # z_r
    dict[tuple[str, str], pulp.LpVariable],  # od_v
    dict[tuple[str, str], pulp.LpVariable],  # td_v
]:
    prob = pulp.LpProblem(name="Ride_Sharing", sense=pulp.LpMinimize)

    # Decision Variables
    yd_r = pulp.LpVariable.dicts(
        name="match",
        indices=((d, r) for d in network.drivers for r in network.riders),
        cat=pulp.LpBinary,
    )
    td_v = {
        (d, v): pulp.LpVariable(
            name=f"departure_time_{(d, v)}",
            lowBound=network.etd[d], upBound=network.ltd[d],
            cat=pulp.LpContinuous,
        )
        for d in network.drivers
        for v in network.locations
    }

    # Auxiliary Variables
    z_r = pulp.LpVariable.dicts(
        name="served_rider",
        indices=list(network.riders),
        cat=pulp.LpBinary,
    )
    od_v = pulp.LpVariable.dicts(
        name="car_occupancy",
        indices=((d, v) for d in network.drivers for v in network.locations),
        lowBound=0, upBound=None, cat=pulp.LpInteger,
    )

    return prob, yd_r, z_r, od_v, td_v


def set_objective(
    network: NetworkVars,
    prob: pulp.LpProblem,
    yd_r: dict[tuple[str, str], pulp.LpVariable],
    z_r: dict[str, pulp.LpVariable],
    default_distance: int = 0,
) -> None:
    # Our objective is to minimize:
    prob.setObjective(
        pulp.lpSum([
            yd_r[d, r] * network.dvsr_ver[r].get('shortest_distance', default_distance)
            for d in network.drivers
            for r in network.riders
        ]) + pulp.lpSum(
            (1 - z_r[r]) * network.dvsr_ver[r].get('shortest_distance', default_distance)
            for r in network.riders
        )
    )


def set_constraints(
    net: NetworkVars,
    prob: pulp.LpProblem,
    yd_r: dict[tuple[str, str], pulp.LpVariable],
    z_r: dict[str, pulp.LpVariable],
    od_v: dict[tuple[str, str], pulp.LpVariable],
    td_v: dict[tuple[str, str], pulp.LpVariable],
    M: int,
):
    for d in net.drivers:
        for r in net.riders:
            if net.vsr[r] not in net.πd[d] or net.ver[r] not in net.πd[d]:
                prob += yd_r[d, r] == 0
    for d in net.drivers:
        prob += pulp.lpSum(
            yd_r[d, r]
            for r in net.riders
            if net.etr[r] < net.etd[d] or net.ltr[r] > net.ltd[d]
        ) == 0

    for r in net.riders:
        prob += pulp.lpSum(yd_r[d, r] for d in net.drivers) <= 1
    for r in net.riders:
        prob += pulp.lpSum(yd_r[d, r] for d in net.drivers) == z_r[r]
    for r in net.riders:
        prob += z_r[r] >= yd_r['driver1', r] + yd_r['driver2', r] - 1
        prob += z_r[r] <= yd_r['driver1', r]
        prob += z_r[r] <= yd_r['driver2', r]
        prob += pulp.lpSum(yd_r[d, r] for d in net.drivers) >= z_r[r]
    for d in net.drivers:
        for v in net.locations:
            prob += od_v[d, v] <= net.qd[d]
    for d in net.drivers:
        prob += pulp.lpSum(yd_r[d, r] * net.num_people[r] for r in net.riders) <= net.qd[d]
    for d in net.drivers:
        for v in net.locations:
            if v in net.predπd_v:
                prob += od_v[d, v] == od_v[d, net.predπd_v[v]] + pulp.lpSum(
                    yd_r[d, r] * net.num_people[r] for r in net.startsπd_v[v]) - pulp.lpSum(
                    yd_r[d, r] * net.num_people[r] for r in net.endsπd_v[v])

            for r in net.riders:
                if d == r:
                    prob += yd_r[d, r] * net.etr[r] <= td_v[d, net.vsr[r]]
                    prob += M - td_v[d, net.ver[r]] >= (M - net.ltr[r]) * yd_r[d, r]
    time_window = 1
    for d in net.drivers:
        for v in net.locations:
            if v in net.predπd_v:
                prob += td_v[d, v] >= td_v[d, net.predπd_v[v]] + net.stv_v_prime[(net.predπd_v[v], v)]

    for d in net.drivers:
        for r in net.riders:
            for v in net.locations:
                for v_prime in net.locations:
                    if v != v_prime:
                        match = int(net.vsr[r] == v and net.ver[r] == v_prime)
                        prob += match * yd_r[d, r] - time_window <= td_v[d, v] - td_v[d, v_prime]
                        prob += match * yd_r[d, r] + time_window >= td_v[d, v] - td_v[d, v_prime]
    for d in net.drivers:
        for i in range(len(net.πd[d]) - 1):
            prob += td_v[d, net.πd[d][i + 1]] >= td_v[d, net.πd[d][i]] + net.stv_v_prime[(net.πd[d][i], net.πd[d][i + 1])]


def solve(prob: pulp.LpProblem) -> None:
    prob.solve()
    # for v in prob.variables():
        # print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
        # print("Objective:", value(model.objective))
    print("Objective:", pulp.value(prob.objective))


def main() -> None:
    network = NetworkVars.default()

    prob, yd_r, z_r, od_v, td_v = make_lp_vars(network)

    set_objective(
        network=network, prob=prob, yd_r=yd_r, z_r=z_r, default_distance=0,
    )

    set_constraints(
        net=network, prob=prob,
        yd_r=yd_r, z_r=z_r, od_v=od_v, td_v=td_v,
        M=1000,
    )

    solve(prob=prob)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 905 COLUMNS
At line 2800 RHS
At line 3701 BOUNDS
At line 3759 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 900 rows, 43 columns and 1821 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
Problem is infeasible - 0.00 seconds
Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer to my question, I will check it. Still, if you consider my simple example for editing my code, we should achieve a feasible solution...because we want to match riders and drivers according to my problem... I edit my last code but again It has a problem with the right answer@PeterSmith